# Problem with DBDesigner

Tags: mysql, database, data-modeling

The DBDesigner can synchronize only with MySQL?

I tried with SQL Server but don't works.

DBDesigner Ver: 4.0.5.6

Tks.

Answer (score 1):

http://fabforce.net/dbdesigner4/ :

DBDesigner 4 is developed and optimized for the open source MySQL-Database to support MySQL users with a powerful and free available design tool.

Comment: But Exists a full version?
I was find in fabforce website but I don't find full version.

Tks.

Comment: I might be totally off-track here, but I think it's been continued as MySQL Workbench: http://dev.mysql.com/workbench/